# Where should i put the function?

Tags: ios, swift, uidevice

I created a function which checks whether the iPhone is charging or not using `UIDevice`. Where should I call the function so that it monitors the status throughout the app session? [The Function is called "connectivityStatus"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2itVg.png), at present it's in `viewWillAppear`.

Language : Swift 3
Platform : iOS 10 (Using UIDevice)

Comment: I bet there's a notification your could listen for to see when the charging state changes.

Comment: Please don't use any of the suggested answers. As Daniel pointed out correctly, there is a notification for this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use a `Timer()`:

```
// in viewDidAppear()
connectivityStatus()
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.function) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

//outside viewDidAppear()
func function(){
    connectivityStatus()
}
```

This check the status every 2 seconds! Hope this Helps!

### NOTE:

If you decide  to update it more often, you can change the value from `timeInterval:` to a smaller one, but be aware that your app might get slower if a lot of processes are going on!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm!

Comment: I don't suggest using the Timer at an interval of 0.5. That would call the function quite often and may slow down your app

Comment: @penatheboss Exactly, using an event-based mechanism (in this case notifications) is almost always the better choice.

Comment: Using a Timer is fine, but the time interval should be at least 3

Comment: I know this is not the best practice, but as long as he wanted to update it very often and without so much code, it is fine. I will update the answer, so that the process doesn't get too messy and slow. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 2):

Hari please define a function in Appdelegate.h and give the defination of the function in Appdelegate.m .   Now you can use this function through the app like this [[Appdelegate **appdelegate**] "Name of your function"]. I hope this will help.   Paste the below code in Appdelegate.m inorder to use **appdelegate** .

```
+(AppDelegate*)appDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

**swift**

```
class func appDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
return (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, A Swift version please!

Comment: @Hari - check the answer

Comment: @xxxy2j - why you said like, beileve yourself, you need to know your value, never ask like `Pls accept this answers` , it is depend up on questioner

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor it for whole application life cycle do it in below method in **AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage something like,

In your `appdelegate`,

```
  func connectivityStatus() -> Bool {
    // define your method body here. I assume return type as bool. you can customize as per your need

    return true // or false as per your requirement
}
```

Now in whatever viewcontroller you want to call this function you can do like,

```
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate


 appDelegate.connectivityStatus() // it will return bool as per your defination in method in appdelegate
```